# Kivy - How to change the colour of every text input if a condition is met

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create some themes in kivy. My program currently has 4 classes/screens. I have manged to be able to change the background colour of all the screens if a condition is met. I have tried to change the colour of all the text input's so intead of white, they are black. This is my code so far

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.clock import *
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class WeatherRoot(ScreenManager, BoxLayout):
    pass


class RegisterPage(Screen, BoxLayout):
    pass


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

def iii(time):
    print("h")
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        TextInput.background_color = (1,1,1,0)

    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Clock.schedule_once(iii)
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
WeatherRoot:
<WeatherRoot>:
    RegisterPage:

<RegisterPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding: [100, 50, 100, 50]
        TextInput:
            font_size: 30
        TextInput:
            font_size: 30
```

The code to change the TextInput colour isn't working.

The background is white but the text-input isn't black as you can see

[image]

How would I be able to change the colour of the TextInput and properties widgets in general (e.g. the text colour of all labels), if a condition is met, with python code?

Thanks in advance

Note - It doesn't work with foreground_color or any of the colour settings like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the concept of object/instance and classes does not differ. By using `TextInput.background_color = (1,1,1,0)` you add or modify the "background_color" property of the TextInput class, not of the objects/instances created based on the TextInput class.

If you want to modify the property of the TextInputs (a.k.a instances/objects created based on the TextInput class) you must access those objects using the kivy methods through the parents:

```py
def iii(time):
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        root = App.get_running_app().root # WeatherRoot instance
        screen = root.screens[0] # RegisterPage instance        
        box_layout = screen.children[0] # BoxLayout instance
        for child in box_layout.children: # childs of box_layout
            if isinstance(child, TextInput): # verify that the child is a TextInput
                child.background_color = (1,1,1,0)
```

I think you have extrapolated that in the case of Window it behaves similar to TextInput, but they are not the same since the first one is an instance of the WindowBase class, it is not a class unlike the second.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would it be right to assume that this will work with other widgets too? For example with a button or a dropdown?

Comment: @JeffBanks It depends on each case, the only thing I could tell you: 1) Review your OOP concepts (take a course if you don't have them), 2) Review the kivy docs, and 3) Review the official kivy tutorials.

Comment: Also, what should I do if I wanted this to happen with input boxes in multiple screens/classes? Would I iterate over root.screens?

Comment: @JeffBanks Yes, I recommend you review what I pointed out above because because of your ignorance I suppose you have thousands of questions but unfortunately the comments of SO is not the right place.

Comment: @JeffBanks Finally, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helps you, if you don't know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @JeffBanks Comments are the worst sources to deduce the mood with which they are written if, since you read them with a certain intonation, then they can be interpreted in a certain way, but if you give them another intonation then they are interpreted in an opposite way. If you consider that I have been rude then I recommend raising a flag pointing it out for a moderator to analyze.